# iOS dealloc crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, dealloc

find a strange code here
I have a viewcontroller, it has an array with books, and click the cell, then push to a detailViewController, detailVC has a variable infoDict,

```
 @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary * infoDict;
```

navigationController push

```
DetailViewController * tDVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
tDVC.infoDict = infoDict;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tDVC animated:YES];
[tDVC release];
```

tap the back button, pop back, and inside dealloc of DetailVC

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];

    NSLog(@"before %d",infoDict.retainCount);
    [infoDict release];
}
```

but when I tap back, in this dealloc app crashes randomly, EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

when move [super dealloc] to the bottom of dealloc, it seems back to normal.
pls help me to understand this , many thanks

Comment: "infoDict" is this a correct your proper instance variable name (seems like should be _infoDict)

Comment: @Injectios of course mate

Comment: so do you have @synthesize infoDict = infoDict;  ?

Comment: yeah kind of @Injectios

Comment: Do you want to say you've searched for at least 5 minutes to resolve that problem and to understand what does happen? That's basics, isn't it? It's described in every book.

Answer (score 4):

`[super dealloc]` deallocates the object itself. If you type `dealloc` and let Xcode autocomplete, you get this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    <#deallocations#>
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Meaning you should release objects and properties *before* you call `[super dealloc]`

Comment: "releases the object itself" you mean "deallocates"?

Answer (score 2):

Your `-dealloc` implementation is out of order. The call to `-[super dealloc]` *must* be the absolute last invocation in the `dealloc` method. When you access the ivar `infoDict`, the compiler is really doing something like `self->infoDict` and by this point, `self` has been deallocated and is no longer valid.

If at all possible, I recommend using `ARC` instead of manually managing memory.

Comment: cool, I will transform my project to Arc next week, thanks man

Answer (score -1):

Try

its better if you use `self.infoDict = nil;` instead of `[infoDict rlease];`

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  NSLog(@"before %d",infoDict.retainCount);
  [infoDict release];

  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: It's definitely not best to use accessors in `-dealloc`. It's best to use ARC and have no need for `-dealloc` anymore, but if you can't, you should not use accessors in `-dealloc` or `-init`

Comment: best is Arc but if not using Arc and as the guy said he is using dealloc so it mean he is not using Arc

Comment: Yep, I got that, my comment was in response to your suggestion that it's better to use the accessors (e.g., `self.infoDict = nil;` in your `-dealloc`. You should not use accessors in deallocation or initialization routines.

Comment: @JasonCoco When I dug into this, for iOS 3.0, Apple's own best practice was setting them to nil, because it correctly handles weird edge-cases around KVO/listeners/etc (IIRC), whereas merely "releasing" can give you some nasty crashes. Do you have a link to prove that there is anything wrong with setting to nil?

Comment: @Adam IMHO it's common sense and OO best practices not to access self while destroying or creating an object. If you have side effects in your accessors, you should execute them—if necessary—in your destructor. Apple have said it during talks and in various papers, but spell it out specifically here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6

Comment: You can also see in the 3.1 release notes (link below) that Apple even changed their behavior to directly release the view and no longer call accessor methods on `UIViewController`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-3/

Comment: UIViewController is a special case - the .view property already breaks Apple's own rules (and always will).